# Django models use id group as ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I am developing one site and need to link table records to group id so I wrote my model for db but when I try to insert foreignkey i receive  errors on makemigrations:

(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Group', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
and
sito_boe.Boe.group_id: (fields.E307) The field sito_boe.Boe.group_id was declared with a lazy reference to 'sito_boe.group', but app 'sito_boe' doesn't provide model 'group'
Here is my model.
I just searched on web and documentation without luck, Anyone can help me?
Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

#Group.auth_group
class Boe(models.Model):
    """Model representing an author."""
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Nome")
    Geo_POS = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Coordinate")
    Luogo = models.TextField(verbose_name="Posizione")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #group_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Gruppo")
    id_boa = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,blank=False,verbose_name="Identificativo boa",help_text='Enter field boaXX')
    group_id = models.ForeignKey('Group.auth_group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.Name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Name']
        verbose_name_plural = "Boe"
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular author instance."""
        return reverse('listaboe', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: The `ForeignKey` to `Group.auth_group` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a foreign key to Group, you can add something like:

```
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="boes", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Currently, you are using "Group.auth_group" rather than Group in your group related foreign key field.

Comment: Thanks, i just tried also with Group but i have the same errors

Comment: You could check your other models which could have a wrong reference to Group as well based on your output. `(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Group', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`